# Android get the selected audio file's duration from storage

Tags: android

I want to get the selected audio file's duration from the storage. What I have accomplished so far is I got the audio file's name. But I want to get the duration of the  mp3 file. How can I do that? When viewing the audio files, they are displayed in a listview and to each file's right side is the duration. I want to get duration string. But I don't have an idea how to do it.

This is the code I'm working on:

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_AUDIO)
        {
            System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO");
            Uri selectedAudioUri = data.getData();
            uploadFilePath = getPath(selectedAudioUri);
            System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + uploadFilePath);
            etSongTitle.setText(uploadFilePath);

        }   

    }
}
```

Do you have some ideas to get the duration? Help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: did you try getduration

Comment: @user2511882 not yet, where do I get the duration?